# How do I allow both fingerprint and password entry on lock/login screen regardless of prompt type?

Tags: login-screen, fingerprint-reader

I have both fingerprint and password login enabled. However each only works when the corresponding prompt is visible.

- When the fingerprint prompt is displayed, entering passwords doesn't work.
- When the password field is displayed, fingerprint scanning doesn't work.
- When both fingerprint prompt and password field are displayed (when unlocking and the fingerprint reading times out), fingerprint scanning doesn't work but password entry does.

[image]

Is there a way to have both login methods work regardless of which prompt is displayed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might not be possible as of now.
I am listing below what suggests it is (at least) complicated, and things you can try.

1. As per [this](https://launchpad.net/%7Efingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fprint),

> At the moment, you cannot type in your password right away when you
> are asked for fingerprint. You need to make the fingerprint
> authentication fail first (swipe wrong finger or let it time out)
> before you are asked for password. This is a limitation of PAM because
> its modules mustn't be threaded and hence cannot support multiple
> means of authentication at the same time. (The old ThinkFinger used to
> do this, but it was a gross hack which caused many troubles.) A
> possible solution to this limitation is to make gdm, screensaver and
> policykit-1 support multiple alternative PAM stacks.

I did not try the suggestion there (which is no more than that, a suggestion), but I found no references to anyone succeeding.

2. As per [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402882/137608),

> pam_fprintd doesn't support entering either the password or a
> fingerprint, as pam_thinkfinger does, because it's a gross hack, and
> could be fixed by having the login managers run 2 separate PAM stacks

Lights of hope, YMMV:

1. See item 1 above.
2. As per [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433982/137608), there is a fork https://github.com/zsxsoft/libfprint-fprintd, although it is old and not maintained.

**Related**:

1. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332149/how-to-login-with-both-password-and-fingerprint
2. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207360/use-multiple-pam-login-methods-at-once
3. https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/pam-authconfig  ("You can set multiple options at the same time...")

Comment: Thanks for answering! It may just be that there is no way in Linux do this currently. I've upvoted and If no one comes up with a solution in the next few days I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @user15656060 - Note that other Linux flavors may have this feature available.